# Imposible instalar Antergos

Tags: linux, windows10

Buneas,

Llevo intentando instalar [Antergos](https://antergos.com/) como segundo sistema operativo (actualmente tengo Windows 10) unos días y cada vez que arranco el live usb installer o live cd installer e incluso el de nvidia se queda la pantalla congelada con el logo de Antergos sobre un fondo blanco, y alguna vez que pasa de esa pantalla empiezan a aparecer un montón de lineas de código (imagen adjunta).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No es un problema del burneado del usb porque lo probé en el portátil de un amigo (con Manjaro) y no hubo problemas. Llegó hasta el escritorio donde podía instalar el sistema.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: La verdad es que por la info del pantallazo no puedo ayudarte, no tengo tanto nivel XDDD pero.... Manjaro se basa en ArchLinux y Archlinux ya no da soporte a sistemas de 32bits... puede que lo estés intentando instalar en un sistema de 32bits. Por descartar...

Comment: Tiene arquitectura de 64 bits :/

Comment: UPDATE: Tras arreglar el problema otro ha surgido. Al hacer login ya en antergos, la pantalla se pone en negro y solo se ve el cursor, pero no lo puedo mover. El ordenador queda completamente bloqueado.

Comment: Podrías publicar la respuesta a como sonseguiste instalar y luego otro pregunta. Respecto a ésta última vete a un tty a ver si puedes entrar por ahí y mirar que pasa.

Comment: @Neoniet En el menu de boot, donde aparece live usb installer apreté 'e' para añadir un parametro al final de la lista. modprobe.blacklist=nouveau